# Limit sync'ed address book entries to bluetooth car-kit

Tags: contacts, bluetooth, sync

Is there an app (because I don't see it as a feature) to limit the address book entries to a particular category when accessing via bluetooth?

My car will only take 1000 phone numbers, but my address book on the phone is about 1400.  My colleagues car will only take 500, and his list is 900 long.

If there was a way to limit the list it would allow it to sync quicker and not miss vital people...

Anyone seen anything like this? When I was using WindowsMobile I used a product from http://www.jetwaremobile.com/ to do this - is there an Android equivalent?

-Craig

Answer (score 1):

Please note, this solution will work on SOME Android phones, but not all of them.

As of right now your best bet is to make a group. Go to Contacts or People (depends on phone), view your groups, and then create a new one (usually done by selecting menu and then Add Group. Then add the contacts you want to that group (it might be easiest to go online from a computer and do this.

Then go into the settings of your groups or from the main contact screen and see if you can only show that group as visible.  On my phone I cannot select individual groups to show and not show. But I think other Android phones can do this. Look for a "View" option.

Comment: (HTC Desire) It has sync'ed my groups from Exchange fine - but no option to View group-by-group. Just the ability to view/not-view synced accounts.

Comment: Yea this functionality doesn't exist. You should be able to email the Google team that works on this somehow, or you can go find the Google group that discusses this and leave your comment there. In the meantime keep an eye out for an app that solves this.

Answer (score 1):

Have there been any progress on this? I did find a program, "Bluetooth File Transfer" from Medieval Software, but have not been able to try it yet.

http://www.medieval.it)

OK, I tried it, but was unsuccessful

Comment: Nope. This just allows you to manage file/media transfers between BT devices.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, and taking inspiration from @webs answer - why not create an additional Google account, enter your Bluetooth contacts in that account (by importing/exporting via the web interface) and sync that to your phone.